# Prolog ERROR: demograph.grf:9:16: Syntax error: Unexpected end of file

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I get this error:
ERROR: demograph.grf:9:16: Syntax error: Unexpected end of file

```
file_to_list(FILE,LIST) :- 
   see(FILE), 
   inquire([],R), % gather terms from file
   reverse(R,LIST),
   seen.

inquire(IN,OUT):-
   read(Data), 
   (Data == end_of_file ->   % done
      OUT = IN 
        ;    % more
      inquire([Data|IN],OUT) ) .
```

Inputfile
http://www.ist.tugraz.at/_attach/Publish/LP/demograph.grf

Comment: See [read/1](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=read/1). Prolog `read/1` is expecting to read a *Prolog term* from the file. The `.grf` file you are reading does not have a complete Prolog term, so it hits the end of file before reading one.

Comment: As your input file does not contain Prolog terms, you should use [`get/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=chario) to read char by char.

Comment: `see`, `seen`, `get` these are all completely outdated built-ins in Prolog - and that since more than 20 years. Use `open/3`, `close/1` and (should you need it) `get_code` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
:- use_module(library(readutil)).
read_header_data(Stream, Header) :-
        open(Stream, read, In),
        read_lines(In, Char),
        read_line_to_codes(In, Header, Tail),
%       read_header_data(Header, Fd, Tail).
        close(In).

    read_lines(Stream, []) :-
  at_end_of_stream(Stream).

read_lines(Stream, [H|T]) :- 
  \+ at_end_of_stream(Stream).
  read(Stream, X),
  read_lines(Stream, T).
```

Not exactly what I want. Output should look like this:

```
Lss =
[[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],[0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]] .
```

Answer (score 1):

Now I get it line by line.

but instead of 0 it writes 48 and for one 49 and for space 32. How does it 0,1 and space.

```
process(File) :-
open(File, read, In),
read_line_to_codes(In, Char1),
process_stream(Char1, In),
close(In).

process_stream(end_of_file, _) :- !.
process_stream('\n', _) :- !.
process_stream(Char, In) :-
process_print(Char, In),
%get_char(In, Char2),
read_line_to_codes(In, Char2),
process_stream(Char2, In).
process_print(Char, _) :-
print(Char),print(' nextChar'),nl.
```